# matrices are not aligned error message inspire of confirming appropriate dimensions for the matrices

Tags: python, pandas

Based on my knowledge of matrix multiplication and comments from other similar questions, seems like this product should work.

`X.shape`
(110302, 32)

`initial_theta.shape`
(32, 1)

`X.dot(initial_theta)`

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-6374e4f84506> in <module>
----> 1 X.dot(initial_theta)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in dot(self, other)
   1061             common = self.columns.union(other.index)
   1062             if len(common) > len(self.columns) or len(common) > len(other.index):
-> 1063                 raise ValueError("matrices are not aligned")
   1064 
   1065             left = self.reindex(columns=common, copy=False)

ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjuDo.png)

Comment: I tested it with numpy and with pandas and both are working for me. What is the exact code you are executing?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjuDo.png I attached the image of code snippet from my Jupyter notebook. I am not adding rest of the code as it's unlikely to help.

Comment: @Iam, adding the rest of your code, or some equivalent code that demonstrates the problem, is the *only* thing that would help.